# Most common number in MYSQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, select, mode

I am trying to get a MYSql statement to spit out the most common number in a field.  I believe I am supposed to use `COUNT(QUANTITY)` but I am confused by which to `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, I can't seem to get the correct MODE (Most common number).

****EDIT****

Here is a sample table:

```
QUANTITY | ORDER_NUMBER
   1         51541
   4         12351
   5         11361
   5         12356
   6         12565
   8         51424
   10        51445
   25        51485
```

The MYSql statement should spit out the number **5** because it appears most often

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT QUANTITY,COUNT(*)
FROM ...
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I tried all of them and this one got me exactly what I was asking for, only 1 number displaying, which is **5** given the example above.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER AS ORDER, COUNT(QUANTITY) as numorders
FROM table 
GROUP BY ORDER_NUMBER
ORDER BY numorders
```

Comment: forgot to to include the actual number so you can tell what that most popular number is...

Answer (score 1):

to get the top 10 `order_number`s do

```
select order_number, count(order_number) as quantity
from your_table
group by order_number
order by quantity desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT QUANTITY, COUNT(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_Q
 FROM MYTABLE
 GROUP BY QUANTITY
 ORDER BY TOTAL_Q DESC
```

this will give you number of quanity from most to least number....